# Android : RemoteViews and setOnClickPendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have a widget and I want to change an image when the user click over a button. How can I do it ? Into RemoteView method i only find setOnClickPendingIntent...I must start the new intent and into thisnew activity I must implement the change ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see this example : https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/PairOfDice

source code is below

```
  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager mgr, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    ComponentName me=new ComponentName(ctxt, AppWidget.class);

    mgr.updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(ctxt, appWidgetIds));
  }

  private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context ctxt, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews updateViews=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, AppWidget.class);

    i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.left_die, IMAGES[(int)(Math.random()*6)]); 
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.left_die, pi);
    updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.right_die, IMAGES[(int)(Math.random()*6)]); 
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.right_die, pi);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.background, pi);

    return(updateViews);
  }
```